Possible reason for inserting a ContentVersion causing a row lock error on ContentFolder?
I've got some code to insert a ContentVersion in a Queueable so that it can be read later by another Queueable or a Platform Event once all the files are prepared.
The insertion is nothing fancy:
ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
    Title = transactionUuid,
    PathOnClient = path,
    VersionData = data
);

Database.insert(contentVersion, AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE);

Id contentDocumentId = [
    SELECT ContentDocumentId
    FROM ContentVersion
    WHERE Id = :contentVersion.Id
    WITH SYSTEM_MODE
]
.ContentDocumentId;

Database.insert(
    new ContentDocumentLink(
        ContentDocumentId = contentDocumentId,
        LinkedEntityId = automatedProcessUserId,
        ShareType = 'V'
    ),
    AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE
);


It works great in scratch orgs. But in one customer org, there is a row lock error on an id that corresponds to a ContentFolder whose name is the id of the current user.
In a scratch org, no ContentFolders even exist when running the code.
As far as I can tell, ContentFolder goes back to the days before ContentDocument and is used to store Document.
So, is there any standard functionality that I might find in a 2016 org that ties these things together and might explain the row lock? I've looked for trigger in custom apex. There are managed package triggers on ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink, so I guess they could be related to it.
It's hard to catch a debug log of this infrequent scenario, so I'm trying to look at it from the analysis end at the same time as trying to get a log. Any help greatly appreciated!

?? ContentFolder organizes files in a library (ContentWorkspace)

Thanks Eric - the bit I don't understand is: Is there something you can set in SF that would make it start putting Files into libraries automatically? I haven't been able to find anything. And I thought that ContentWorkspace is on its way to deprecation

a trigger on ContentDocumentLink or ContentDocument could certainly do automation that added files to folders.  Is the customer org using Salesforce CRM user = true on User record but not in your scratch org? There are a whole mess of schema objects related to ContentFolder and perhaps some user has a long-running txn dealing with files  that is holding locks too long.  Your solution might be a retry mechanism in your queueable

@Aidan, I'm myself interested in the subject, see here. I don't think Folders (00l...) have anything to do with ContentFolders (07H...) and Documents have nothing to do with the subject. On one prod org I see ContentFolders being created every couple of weeks, but Documents and Folders fell out of use 2 years ago. Or have I overlooked something?

@FelixvanHove I may have been misreading the docs. Like in your question, I think that they are personal folders but I don't understand why some orgs have them and some don't. The actual application for this hit a different limit for Files (200k created per day), so we had to give up on this anyway

@Aidan, thank you, really appreciate your feedback. For a possible, but very incomplete explanation for the phenomenon see here.
